# Angular Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace

Tags: angular

I'm fairly new to Angular. I am not able to generate new components.
I opened the Integrated Terminal to the folder I want to create it

```
ng generate component modulo
```

and the following error appears:

```
Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace.
```

I've created other projects before and had no problems.

Comment: You need to run that command when you're in a directory with an angular project (`angular.json`)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the directory of angular project then run this command